# Drupal 8 Jquery/Ajax Views Arguments

Tags: views, javascript, ajax

Setup: I have two contextual filters, service area and ID.

In my view if I send {service_area}/{id} i get back the OR query, which is what I want. My question is, when I try to use Jquery to return this query, I do not get back the expected result, which is the OR of these two arguments.

Here is my code:

```
(function($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.searchresults = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      $('.currentFilters', context).once('search').click(function () {
        
        //hard set variable for this example.
        let args = [];
        args[0] = 'antelope valley';
        args[1] = '221';

        $.ajax({
          url: '/views/ajax',
          type: 'post',
          data: {
            view_name: 'webform_submissions',
            view_display_id: 'page_1',
            
            //This is where it may be causing an issue. I pass an array with the arguments, but no avail
            view_args: args,
          },
          ...
        });
      });
    },
  }
})(jQuery);
```

In my view I am able to see this OR if I preview with contextual filters as as seen in the image below:

[image]

If I just send `service_area` by itself as the argument, it will work. So my question is, what is the correct way of sending multiple arguments in ajax, any references/blogs to help me would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I needed to pass a string not an object, the lack of documentation confused me.

```
    let args = 'antelope valley';
    args = args + '/207'

    $.ajax({
      url: '/views/ajax',
      type: 'post',
      data: {
        view_args: args,
 ...
```